# Which zero vector is the span of the empty set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a simple case, I have two vector spaces ${\mathsf{R}}^2$ and ${\mathsf{R}}^3$. The zero vectors in these vector spaces are of course ${\mathit{0}}_{{\mathsf{R}}^2} = (0, 0)$ and ${\mathit{0}}_{{\mathsf{R}}^3} = (0, 0, 0)$. And ${\mathit{0}}_{{\mathsf{R}}^2} \neq {\mathit{0}}_{{\mathsf{R}}^3}$.

But by the definition of the span of the empty set, $\operatorname{span}(\emptyset) = \{ \mathit{0}\hspace{0.15em} \}$. Which zero vector is this?

There is only one empty set (right?), so we must have different $\operatorname{span}$ operators, like one for every vector space. How is this reconciled? What does ${\operatorname{span}}_{\mathsf{V}}(S_1) = {\operatorname{span}}_{\mathsf{W}}(S_2)$ imply for some vector spaces $\mathsf{V}$ and $\mathsf{W}$ and sets $S_1 \subseteq \mathsf{V}$ and $S_2 \subseteq \mathsf{W}$?

Comment: span operator is general, but you can only span vectors that belong to the same space... so it is understood that the arguments inside a span are all part of the same vector space

Comment: But are you sure that we define span also for empty set?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan But the empty set is a subset of every vector space. So we really must specify the vector space in order to say $\operatorname{span}(\emptyset) = \{ \mathit{0} \}$ because there's not enough information to determine what $\mathit{0}$ this is. Right?

Comment: @Fabrizio My definition of $\operatorname{span}$ comes from *Linear Algebra* by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence. The definition is: Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a vector space $\mathsf{V}$. The **span** of $S$, denoted $\operatorname{span}(S)$, is the set consisting of all linear combinations of the vectors in $S$. For convenience, we define $\operatorname{span}(\emptyset) = \{ \mathit{0}\hspace{0.15em} \}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pick a vector space with respect to which you want to span; you can't just say "the span of the empty set" without reference to a vector space.

Once you've decided which vector space you're using, the answer should be clear.